# How to pass optional Jenkins parameter into a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have two Jenkins jobs. Neither uses a Jenkinsfile under source control. Instead, each job has a pipeline script saved inside the Jenkins job itself. The pipeline scripts of the two jobs differ in only one way - one of them prompts the user to choose a parameter called VERSION when running the job and the other one does not. The pipeline scripts are identical in all other respects.

I am trying to consolidate the two pipeline scripts into a single Jenkinsfile under source control. I have defined the VERSION variable thus:

```
def version = (VERSION != "") ? "version=${VERSION}" : ""
```

As I understand it (I might be wrong), this means "if VERSION is entered by the user running the job, set $version to $VERSION. If VERSION is not entered by the user running the job, set $version to null". I then call $version further down my Jenkinsfile.

When I run the Jenkins job where VERSION is NOT selected by the user, the job fails with this error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: VERSION for class:
```

Any thoughts on how I can optionally pass VERSION into my Jenkinsfile depending on whether the user has selected this option when running the job or not?

Comment: It is tough to guess given the lack of code provided, but it sounds like `VERSION` is a parameter and should be accessed from within its map via `params.VERSION`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If `VERSION` is the job's parameter, you should change as following:

```
def version = params.VERSION ? "version=${params.VERSION}" : ""
```

Comment: Many thanks to Matt and yong. Your solution was correct. I replaced VERSION with params.VERSION and now it works. Thank you!